# sp_rename and reserved words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to rename a table to CASE which is a reserved word. WHen using delimiters such as [] , I get the name [CASE], which is not my intent. The obvious answer here is to not use the reserved word as a name, however , I am a contractor on a project and don't know what all I will break by changing the name.

Comment: It's a bad idea to name the table CASE. Are you sure you _need_ to rename it that way ?

Comment: The name would be `CASE`, it doesn't really "store" the brackets, they are just used when using that table to distinguish it from the `CASE` expression. But once created, you can do: `SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'CASE'` and will get a result

Comment: Other than the fact that naming the table CASE, or any other reserved word, is a terrible idea, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Every query will need to refer to that table using brackets. Any query that doesn't won't compile. This also implies changing every query that refers to that table. It's actually much easier to pick a name that isn't reserved, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: This is a dumb problem. Someone at the place you are contracting for is asking for a dumb thing. I would advise you to tell them it's dumb seeing as how they do not seem to grasp the dumbness of the thing they are doing.

Comment: You are great at inter office politics aren't you Zane ? :)  The idea is to get the structure across and softly suggest changes. But I did need the laugh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using a reserved keyword for a table name is not a good idea.

Doing so would require every query that refers to the table to use brackets. The query becomes more complex to read, writing a query against that table becomes more error prone, etc...

More to the point, you can save all that trouble if you find a name that isn't a reserved keyword. This simple solution has no drawback and will save headaches in the future.

Comment: The simple solution might actually be more likely to cause a headache in the future. If the table is called `case` and referenced as `[case]` then there should be no issue (except if it has to interface with buggy third party utilities and code). If the table is called `wibble` and referenced as `wibble` and that later becomes a reserved word the code might have to change!

Comment: I believe the risk of a normal table name (say, if he chose for example `CourtCase` or `BriefCase`) becoming a reserved word is pretty low.